How to migrate fork like svn structure to Azure git?
We have an svn repo with structure similar to this:

svn repo

Project1

trunk
tags
branches


Project2

trunk
tags
branches





Where Project2 is a copy of Project1. In git(hub) terms one might call Project2 a fork of Project1.
How do I migrate both projects to Azure in a way that Project2 be a fork of Project1 and having the ability to merge changes between them? We do full merges of Project1 into Project2 to keep Project2 synced and only some commits of Project2 are merged to Project1.


How do I migrate both projects to Azure in a way that Project2 be a fork of Project1.

There is currently no direct way to do this. SVN and Git use different version control system. SVN is centralized while Git is distributed, which gives every developer their own copy of the repository, complete with its own local history and branch structure. See the differences between SVN and Git from this blog.
You can follow this doc Learn how to migrate from Subversion (SVN) to Git, including history to migrate your project1 to a Git repo and fork it to create project2.

A new fork is basically a clone of the original repo pushed to a new remote repo. The fork is independent of the original repo, and is a complete copy unless you specify a single branch. When you create a new fork, include all branches.


You can merge between project1(original repo) and project2(fork repo) easily via pull request. For example:




Update
Assuming that you have completed the migration of Project1 and Project2, the corresponding Azure Git repos are Project1 and Project2 respectively. Now, let's "add fork association" between Project1 and Project2.

Create a new fork based on Project1.



Go to your local machine. Run git clone --mirror {The URL of your Project2.git}
cd {The folder of Project2.git}
Run git push --mirror {The URL of your fork repo. In my example, it's the URL of NewProject2}.

Then you can see all the code, branches, tags of Project2 in the fork repo.
Note: This method is only used as a workaround to save the history and code of Project2 and keep the fork relationship between two repos. Since there is no merge-base between Project1 and the new fork repo, PR merge will be impossible.
Based on the current situation, here are some suggestions:

Integrate all the code into one project, and then create a new fork repo to continue future work. For previous history, use the above method as a workaround.
Migrate Project1/trunk and Project2/trunk respectively as two branches of the Git repo. (I have not tested it and I don’t know if some information will be missing.) If this is okay for you, it seems that there is no need to fork the repo. You can Version control by creating new branches.


Ok but this way I lose all the code in Project2 that is different from Project1. After doing what you propose can I delete all files in Project2 (fresh clone) and copy paste all files from svn Project2 then push them. This way I suppose we would lose all history to svn Project2 but would be able to work in git using our old svn workflow. Am I correct? Is it viable to port svn Project2/trunk as a branch to git Project1 and then make a clone from that branch (meaning we decide we don't need Project2 tags and branches)?

Yes, you are right. If you still want all the code and history in Project2, you can try to also migrate Project2 to a Git repo. Then add a fork association between the two git repo (Project1.git and Project2.git).  However, PR merge between Project1 and Project2 will not be possible because there is no merge-base between the two repos. See the update above for the detailed info.
